# Merge json objects into one

Tags: json, object, merge, jq

I'm trying to merge some json objects using jq.

It seems too complicated for me ^^

I have a JSON which looks like this

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": "192.168.0.1",
    "kv_key": "test2_key",
    "kv_value": "test2_value",
    "location": "here"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": "192.168.0.2",
    "kv_key": "test1_key",
    "kv_value": "test1_value",
    "location": "here"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": "192.168.0.1",
    "kv_key": "test2_key",
    "kv_value": "test2_value",
    "location": "here"
  },
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": "192.168.0.1",
    "kv_key": "test3_key",
    "kv_value": "test3_value",
    "location": "here"
  }
]
```

And I want something like this

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": [
        "192.168.0.1",
        "192.168.0.2"
    ],
    "key_value": [
        {
            "test1_key": "test1_value",
            "test2_key": "test2_value",
            "test3_key": "test3_value"
        }
    ],
    "location": "here"
  }
]
```

I managed to make something work for the ip field only

```
jq 'map(. |= (group_by(.name) | map(first + {ip: map(.ip)})))' <<< "${json}"
```

Probably not the best way to do this and I'm clearly stuck on the key/value part.

Thx for you help !

amans

Answer (score 2):

If all items have the same keys, you can make this generic by using `to_entries` to split the objects into an array of key-value pairs, `transpose` them, and combine them again using `from_entries`. Duplicate values can be eliminated using `unique`, and singletons can be generated by checking for the presence of a second item using `select(has(1))`:

```bash
group_by(.name) | map(map(to_entries) | transpose | map(first + {value: (
  map(.value) | unique | select(has(1)) // first
)}) | from_entries)
```

To account for merging `.kv_key` - `.kv_value` pairs into objects under a new `.key_value` key, you can make the conversion beforehand, and then collapse all object-only arrays found by `select(all(type == "object"))` into one object using `add`:

```bash
map(del(.kv_key, .kv_value) + {key_value: {(.kv_key): .kv_value}})
| group_by(.name) | map(map(to_entries) | transpose | map(first + {value: (
    map(.value) | unique | select(all(type == "object")) |= [add]
    | select(has(1)) // first
  )}) | from_entries)
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": [
      "192.168.0.1",
      "192.168.0.2"
    ],
    "location": "here",
    "key_value": {
      "test1_key": "test1_value",
      "test2_key": "test2_value",
      "test3_key": "test3_value"
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IjYFRtSFoig)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```bash
$ jq 'group_by(.name) 
| map(first + {ip: map(.ip) | unique} 
            + {key: map(.kv_key) | unique}
            + {value: map(.kv_value) | unique}) 
| map(. + {key_value: [.key,.value] | transpose | map({(.[0]):.[1]}) | add}) 
| map(del(.key,.value,.kv_key,.kv_value))' file

[
  {
    "name": "test_name",
    "cpu": "1",
    "ip": [
      "192.168.0.1",
      "192.168.0.2"
    ],
    "location": "here",
    "key_value": {
      "test1_key": "test1_value",
      "test2_key": "test2_value",
      "test3_key": "test3_value"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a straightforward approach that makes no assumptions about the keys in any of the objects. It uses a generic function that might also be useful elsewhere:

```
def meld($obj): 
   reduce ($obj|keys_unsorted[]) as $k(.; 
    if has($k)|not then .[$k] = $obj[$k] 
    elif .[$k] == $obj[$k] then . 
    else ( .[$k] | type) as $t 
    | if $t == "array" then .[$k] += [$obj[$k]] 
      else .[$k]=[ .[$k], $obj[$k]] 
      end 
    end); 

 reduce .[] as $x ({}; meld($x))
```

This is a quasi-lossless solution. You could easily modify it e.g. to use `unique` or otherwise handle duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is:

```
group_by(.name)
| map(
    reduce .[] as $e(
        first | del(.ip, .kv_key, .kv_value);
        .ip += [ $e.ip ]
        | .key_value[$e.kv_key] = $e.kv_value
    )
    | .ip |= unique
)
```

- First `group_by(.name)` build the appropriate group.
- After that each group is handled individually:
- Take the first element of each group as a template but remove some things
- Incrementally add stuff to the template using the iteration variable `$e`
- Fixup `ip` by making it unique.